Is it necessary to call db.Close() if MySQL crashes?
I have an golang app which uses MySQL as the backend DB. The app opens a *sql.DB using sql.Open and then calls PingContext https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#DB.PingContext to make sure we can talk to it.
This is the code for establishing the connection
func (se *Executor) connect(ctx context.Context) error {
    if se.DB != nil {
        // If DB handle exists, ping it to make sure it's still alive
        return se.DB.PingContext(ctx)
    }

    // Create a DB handle
    dsn := fmt.Sprintf(mysqlDNSFormat, se.User, se.Pass, mysqlSocketPath)
    var err error
    se.DB, err = sql.Open("mysql", dsn)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Failed to connect to mysql %v", err)
        return err
    }

    // Make sure we can ping the DB before returning
    if err = se.DB.PingContext(ctx); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Failed during ping to mysql %v", err)
        return err
    }
    return nil
}

First time this function is called we will setup se.DB and then subsequent calls only ping the database to make sure it is up and running before executing any queries. If a DB restarts, then it is possible that pings start failing. In this situation is it necessary to call db.Close()? Documentation on PingContext says

PingContext verifies a connection to the database is still alive, establishing a connection if necessary.

which implies that once the DB is back up again, PingContext will start succeeding. It does not say if the DB has to be closed and reopened again. The documentation on db.Open also suggests that the function should be called just once.

The returned DB is safe for concurrent use by multiple goroutines and maintains its own pool of idle connections. Thus, the Open function should be called just once. It is rarely necessary to close a DB.


not sure what you mean by 'a new version of DB' - clarify that concisely please. Can't imagine any connections being valid if a 'new version ...' is rolled out. Have you tried a scenario such that the current is closed/replaced. No sense in keeping a dead handle. clean up and refresh imo.

what i meant by new version of db is that we can have scenarios where db restarts. (mysql is deployed inside a container and for operational reasons patches,bug fixes etc, we can roll out a new version, this will result in db getting restarted)

Call Close() to release the resources held by sql.DB.   The code in the question does not require the application to call Close(), but it's possible that other code does. For example, if the application creates and discards Executor values, then se.DB.Close() should be called before discarding the Exectutor.

It is expected that the SQL driver handles failing connections, for example Go-MySQL-Driver says: “Automatic handling of broken connections.”
Note that only because you can ping the database, it is not guaranteed that the connection is still alive on the next request.
Best would be to just send the request and when it fails due to network issues use ping until the database is back up, to avoid repeatedly building failing requests.
